# Python 3 Imaplib - (Errors : EXPUNGE failed ,BAD [b'Command Argument Error. 11'] ) Unable to delete the mails from Microsoft service account

Tags: python-3.x, mail-server, imaplib

Trail 1 :

```
 result, data = mail.uid("STORE", str(message_id), "+X-GM-LABELS", '"\\Trash"')
```

o/p :

```
BAD [b'Command Argument Error. 11']
```

Trail 2 :

```
result, data = mail.uid('STORE', str(message_id)  , '+FLAGS', '(\\Deleted)') 
print("Deleted the mail : " , result ,"-", details_log[4])
                
result, data = mail.uid('EXPUNGE', str(message_id))
print("result",result)
print("data",data)
```

o/p :

```
Deleted the mail :  OK
result NO
data [b'EXPUNGE failed.']
```

Issue : After Expunge , I even tried to close and logout the connection , but still it doesnt get deleted.

Comment: X-GM-LABELS is gmail only.  O365 seems to have expunge problems...

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but for anyone who reads it later on:

When using imaplib's `select` function to choose a mailbox to view (in my case, the "Inbox" mailbox), I had the `readonly` argument set to `True`, to be safe, but this blocked me from deleting emails in Microsoft Outlook. I set it to `False` and was able to delete emails with the `store` and `expunge` methods:

```
conn.select("Inbox", readonly=False)

# modify search query as you see fit
typ, data = conn.search(None, "FROM", "scammer@whatever.com")

for email in data[0].split():
    conn.store(email, "+FLAGS", "\\Deleted")

conn.expunge()
conn.close()
conn.logout()
```